# python accessing and updating mysql from simultaneously running processes

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have 2 different python processes (running from 2 separate terminals) running separately at the same time accessing and updating mysql. It crashes when they are using same table at the same time. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: what crashes ? the python or MySQL ? what type of query (read or update ) ?

Comment: python crashes and it is update.

Comment: Need some more details on what is the error messages and how are you inserting data

Answer (score 0):

Are you using myisam or innodb?  I suggest using innodb since it has a better table/record locking flexibility for multiple simultaneous updates.